# How to make a cell of TAdvStringGrid editable?

Tags: c++, c++builder

I am trying to implement a filter using the component TAdvStringGrid. My requirement is that I want the first row of this component to be editable when double clicked, so that the user can filter data. Borland C++ Builder is used to help achieve this task.

I found this event OnCanEditCell. 
TCanEditCellEvent = procedure (Sender:TObject;Arow,Acol:longint;var canedit:boolean) of object;

Within this function I've set canedit = true.

This doesn't seem to work. Probably I need to do something more. I am new to Windows and GUI development. So any help would be great. Do I need to call this function from the OnDblClickCell event? How can I get it working?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out
[this C++ demo](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/asg21.asp) from TMS?